# java. Remote server returns 503 error with page, that contains some text. How Get this text?

Tags: java, http, connection, request, inputstream

Server Errors below:

> If an error occurred, a HTTP status code 503 (Service Unavailable)
>   will be returned. The MIME type will be set in accordance with the
>   format parameter that was specified in the request. The body of the
>   the returned page will contain the string "Error:" followed by a
>   string with further details. If XHTML was requested, this message will
>   appear somewhere in the document inside a
>
> element. If plain
>   text was requested, it will appear on the first line in the document.

So, I send request with wrong parameters -> server returns error 503 and page with text that describe where problem.

I use the java code below:

```
static BufferedReader getReader(String urlString) throws IOException {

        HttpURLConnection connection;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);

        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream()));

        System.out.println(urlString);

        return reader;
    }
```

And when server returns 503 - java throws Exception. But, how can I get text, that server return??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getResponseCode()` and `getResponseMessage()` methods of `HttpURLConnection` class.

Invoke them after you have built the connection object but before you are getting stream from the connection.

Comment: getResponseMessage() returns: "Service Unavailable". But, I need Text on Page, for example: "Error: The number of columns must be an integer greater than or equal to 1".

Comment: Does the server return the mentioned message? If so, invoke getErrorStream() of HttpURLConnection instance to read the additional information.